# How to for loop with TreeMap in Java

Tags: java

I've been trying to print out a Map to a string but at the same time adding additional item in the process. This is what I'm trying to achieve this: "---\n---\n---\n" But some how it returns like this: "\n---\n---\n---"
Anyone have any idea how to fix this?

```
  //this is my TreeMap
   {
        board.put(0,"-");
        board.put(1,"-");
        board.put(2,"-");
        board.put(3,"-");
        board.put(4,"-");
        board.put(5,"-");
        board.put(6,"-");
        board.put(7,"-");
        board.put(8,"-");
    }

//this is the part I'm trying to work on
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        for ( position = 0; position <= 8; position++) {
            if(position % 3 == 0){
                result.append("\n");
            }
            result.append(board.get(position));
        }
        return result.toString();
```

Comment: how is the output you expect in the StringBuilder object?

Comment: So all you want to change is not having `\n` at the beginning and instead at the end? Then why do you not just change your condition to `if(position != 0 && position % 3 == 0)` to not add the linebreak at the beginning and then just do `result.append("\n");` once the loop is done running. Seems simple enough and not really complicated to think of

Comment: Append the value before the check for `positon % 3 == 0`..

Comment: Besides: why are you using a TreeMap here? Why not simply use a list, or just an array? Remember: arrays/list **map** values to int keys, starting from 0, to some n. That is exactly what you are doing with your TreeMap. You add an abstraction that isnt necessary at all?!

Answer (score 1):

0 is divisible by 3. In the initial state, your for loop executes the if statement because `0 % 3 == 0` is `true`. Change your if to this:

```
if(position != 0 && position % 3 == 0)
```

Or you can start position from 1 and handle the 0th input by yourself before the for loop.

Comment: Or you can move the line ```result.append(board.get(position));``` before the if statement.

Comment: Also, use an ```ArrayList```, your code will get a performance boost.